# How can I simplify $\frac{3^{n+1} + 3^{n-1}}{3^{n+2} + 3^n}$?

Tags: logarithms

This problem got me thinking hard: 
$$\frac{3^{n+1} + 3^{n-1}}{3^{n+2} + 3^n}$$
Considering the fact that the common base is '$3$', I decided to do this:
$$\log_3\left(\frac{(n+1)(n-1)}{(n+2)(n)}\right)$$
$$\log_3\left(\frac{n^2-n+n+1}{n^2+2n}\right)$$
$$\log_3\left(\frac{n^2 + 1}{n^2 + 2n}\right)$$
$$\log_3\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)$$
I am not 100% sure if have simplified the problem. I need some clarification.

Comment: Try to multiply on $\frac{3^{-(n-1)}}{3^{-(n-1)}}$

Answer (score 3):

You're kidding? A sledgehammer to crack a nut?

Factor out $3^{n-1}$ in the numerator and denominator to get eventually $\dfrac13$.

Comment: +1 for First line :D - You're kidding? A sledgehammer to crack a nut?

Comment: How about a "sledgehammer to crack a nut" meme? In that vein, you could use induction to show the value is $1/3$ for all n.

Comment: Or *ab absurdo*…

Comment: Hahahaha.. Arrrggh! I have this habit of treating problems like this as log problems.

Comment: Logarithmomania?

Answer (score 3):

Factor out by $3^n $ to get

$$\frac{3^n (3+3^{-1})}{3^n (3^2+3^0)} $$

$$\frac {3+3^{-1}}{10}=\frac {1}{3} $$

Answer (score 2):

Why are taking logarithm? No need of that. It's just simple Indices.

$\dfrac{3^{n+1} + 3^{n-1}}{3^{n+2} + 3^n}
=\dfrac{3^{n-1}\left(3^2+1\right)}{3^n\left(3^2+1\right)}
=\dfrac{3^{n-1}}{3^n}
=\dfrac{1}{3}$

Comment: Sorry, I have this habit of treating problems like this as logarithms.

Comment: ok then just practice this type of problems more and more.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{3^{n+1}+3^{n-1}}{3^{n+2}+3^n}=\frac{3^{n-1}(3^2+1)}{3^{n-1}(3^3+3)}=\frac{10}{30}=\frac 13$$
This shows your simplification is incorrect for a number of reasons:

- $\log(3^{n+1}+3^{n-1})\neq \log(3^{n+1})\log(3^{n-1})$. The $\log$ rule works the other way: $\log(a)+\log(b)=\log(ab)$
- You cannot simplify $\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+2n}$ to $\frac{1}{2n}$: big no-no. You can simplify *multiplied* expressions, not $summed$ expressions. For instance $\frac{n(n+1)}{(n+3)(n+1)}=\frac{n}{n+3}$ is fine.